# Is this material found on my kitchen floor from some rodent?

Tags: pest

I woke up and found some strange looking material on my kitchen floor. One each on two different days.
Please see image attached.

Any thoughts on what this might be?[image]

Comment: The 'fluffy' bits look like feathers to me.

Comment: Off hand it looks like dead dried skin with fur or down attached.  Probably some animal is bringing it in from somewhere, or it is falling down or blown from underneath something like a fridge.

Comment: Leathery skin and feathers.  Do you have an Emu?  :)

Comment: The "feathery" part might be floating seed bits (similar to, but not actually dandelion) and the other dried up leafy bits.

Comment: If you have mice, you will find droppings.

Comment: Thank you all. No findings yet and no new droppings.